# Bootstrap modal - hide one then show another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've been using jQueryUI for a long time now but have recently made the switch to Bootstrap for aesthetic reasons.  I am now struggling with what I would expect to be a simple issue and wondered if it's something that others more familiar with Bootstrap can help me with.

I have a generic function for creating dialogs on-the-fly and there are occasions where I show a dialog with no buttons (when processing something), and then swap it to a dialog that does have buttons (process complete - click OK, for example).  I'm not trying to define a set process here so I'm basically saying I want to be able to close one dialog and open another whenever needed.  This is where the problem comes in.

With Bootstrap the dialogs animate in and out, and I like that and want to keep it.  I don't want to do it when swapping dialogs though.  I can do this by removing the class `fade` from the first dialog when it shows, and from the second dialog before it shows, and that works great.  I then add the class to the second dialog so that it will animate out.  However, the animation goes wrong when I do this and there's an ugly flash where the background div should fade out gently.

I've put together a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue.  You can click the close button on the first dialog to see what the fade out animation *should* look like.

Any help would be appreciated before I start digging into the Bootstrap source files.

http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/0302gLav/1/

**tl;dr**

Look at the jsfiddle - click "show dialog 2" - click "ok".  I want to get rid of the black flash at the end.

**CSS**

```
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");
.modal {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog1" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Dialog 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">This is the first modal dialog</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="dialog-ok" class="btn btn-default">Show dialog 2</button>          
        <button type="button" id="dialog-close" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>          
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dialog2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Dialog 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">This is the second modal dialog</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>          
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function showDialog2() {
    $("#dialog1").removeClass("fade").modal("hide");
    $("#dialog2").modal("show").addClass("fade");
}

$("#dialog1").modal("show");

$("#dialog-ok").on("click", function() {
    showDialog2();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I don't like to answer my own question, but I've got a solution that is 100% foolproof (as far as I can tell).  I've ended up going for a solution that checks for an existing dialog and modifies that, rather than hiding it and showing a new one.

Here's a working jsfiddle (using echo in the ajax call where it normally loads a html template)...

http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/0302gLav/9/

The code is part of a larger library I'm working on, but I'll post it here anyway as it may well prove useful to others.

**JavaScript Library**

```
(function () {

    var _defaultOptions = {
        backdrop: "static",
        close: true,
        keyboard: true
    };

    window.bootstrap = {
        modal: {
            show: function (options) {

                options = $.extend(_defaultOptions, options);

                var buttonText = "";

                for (var key in options.buttons) {

                    options.buttons[key].id = "button_" + key.split(" ").join("");

                    var button = options.buttons[key];

                    buttonText += "<button type=\"button\" " +
                        "id=\"" + button.id + "\" " +
                        "class=\"btn " +
                        (typeof (button.class) == "undefined" ? "btn-default" : button.class) + "\" " +
                        (typeof (button.dismiss) == "undefined" ? "" : "data-dismiss=\"modal\" ") + ">" +
                        key + "</button>";
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: "templates/bootstrap-modal.html"
                })
                .done(function (data) {
                    data = data
                        .replace("{:Title}", options.title)
                        .replace("{:Body}", options.body)
                        .replace("{:Buttons}", buttonText);

                    var $modal = $("#bootstrap-modal");
                    var existing = $modal.length;

                    if (existing) {
                        $modal.html($(data).find(".modal-dialog"));
                    }
                    else {
                        $modal = $(data).appendTo("body");
                    }

                    for (var key in options.buttons) {
                        var button = options.buttons[key];
                        if (typeof (button.callback) !== undefined) {
                            $("#" + button.id).on("click", button.callback);
                        }
                    }

                    $modal.off("shown.bs.modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function(e) {
                        if (typeof(options.onshow) === "function") {
                            options.onshow(e);
                        }
                    });

                    if (!existing) {
                        $modal.modal(options);
                    }

                    if (options.large === true) {
                        $modal.find(".modal-dialog").addClass("modal-lg");
                    }

                    if (options.close === false) {
                        $modal.find("button.close").remove();
                    }
                });
            },
            hide: function (callback) {
                var $modal = $("#bootstrap-modal");

                if (!$modal.length) return;

                $modal.on("hidden.bs.modal", function(e) {
                    $modal.remove();
                    if (typeof(callback) === "function") {
                        callback(e);
                    }
                });

                $modal.modal("hide");
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

**Template HTML**

```
<div id="bootstrap-modal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">{:Title}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">{:Body}</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        {:Buttons}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example usage:**

```
bootstrap.modal.show({
    title: "Dialog Title",
    body: "<p>This is the dialog body and can contain any old html rubbish.</p>",
    buttons: {
        Close: {
            dismiss: true
        }
    }
});
```

**Further options explained**

```
bootstrap.modal.show({
    backdrop: true,                     // show the backdrop
    close: true,                        // show the close button
    keyboard: true,                     // allow the keyboard to close the dialog
    title: "Dialog Title",
    body: "<p>This is the dialog body and can contain any old html rubbish.</p>",
    buttons: {
        Button1: {
            class: "btn-primary",           // any class you want to add to the button
            dismiss: false,                 // does this button close the dialog?
            callback: function() {          // button click handler
                // the button was clicked - do something here
            }
        },
        Button2: {
            // options as defined as above.  You can have as many buttons as you want
        }
    },
    onshow: function(e) {
        // this will trigger when the dialog has completed the show animation
    }
});
```

and

```
bootstrap.modal.hide(function(e) {
    // this will trigger when the dialog has completed the hide animation
});
```

All the options in the `show()` method are optional, but obviously you'll want a title and a body.

Answer (score 4):

```
function showDialog2() {
$("#dialog1").removeClass("fade").modal("hide");
$("#dialog2").addClass("fade").modal("show");
```

}

you want to be  [this](http://jsfiddle.net/esrefktorun/0302gLav/3/)

Comment: Thanks, but there is a blatant animation between the 2 dialogs.  If you look at my jsfiddle you will see that there isn't.

Comment: removing 'fade' class worked for me, there is a bug in this fiddle, fade class must be removed from the second dialog too, instead of adding it

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED**:

I added a `click()` handler for your last button with an added test identifier `id="test"` where the dialog and the background gets faded out with the [`fadeOut()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) effect. The important thing is to fade out the element `.modal-backdrop` which encapsules both the dialog and background:

```
$("#test").on("click", function () {
    $(".modal-backdrop").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

## JsFiddle

Comment: Thanks, that's not actually that bad.  I want to leave it using the in-built animation that comes with Bootstrap though.  For example, the class `in` is what handles the animation of the dialog and in future that may be changed to allow other options, so I don't want to hard-code anything that is currently done by Bootstrap.  See here for an example... http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/fvr5Lpnn/2/

Comment: I like what you did with the `removeClass("in");` but I do understand how you are handling the dialogs and why hardcoding something is not really the clever alternative. That is what I tried not doing in the first place but it seems when you override default functionality, the flickering occurs.

Comment: Exactly my problem, yes.  The solution I have in place at the moment is pretty much this answer (with the use of the `in` class).  I'm trying to keep it as generic as possible as it's part of a web product that is live on over 40 customer sites.  Whenever new options are added to the controls used in the sites I expose these options to the customers via their site admin pages.  It will be a lot simpler for me to use the existing Bootstrap functionality if at a later date I simply need to change a class from `in` to `bounce`, for example.  I do appreciate the help though, nonetheless :)

Comment: I totally agree. I came up with a better alternative, but nonetheless it is dirty coding right now. ;-) I re-added the built in animation property from Bootstrap `data-dismiss="modal"` and just fading out the `.modal-backdrop` element which encapsules both the dialog and background. See updated answer!

Comment: Many thanks again, but I still wasn't happy as this won't trigger any of the event handlers that Bootstrap modal uses, so it's not future-proof.  I've gone for a solution that totally resolves all the issues I can think of and have posted it as an answer.  Thanks for your help, and definitely +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I've code how to close an opened modal before opening another one.

```
$('[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click', function() { //On click a button which call a modal
    if(($(".modal").data('bs.modal') || {}).isShown){ //If a modal is shown
        var modal = $(".modal.in"); // Get the current element
        $(modal).modal('hide'); // Hide the current modal
    }
});
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks, but no.  If you read the question again you'll see that I wanted to get rid of the animation between closing one dialog and opening another.  Modifying the existing dialog was the most precise way to go.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but might help somebody with the same problem.

Removing the `fade` class when showing the new modal is showing the backdrop without a `fade` class either.

For a clean transition, hiding the current modal and showing the new one without fade, but with fade out on closing:

```js
// hide the existing modal, but without fade animation
$("#existing-modal").removeClass("fade").modal("hide");

// show the new modal without fade animation, but enable the fade animation for later
$("#new-modal").removeClass("fade").modal("show").addClass("fade");

// enable fade animation of the backdrop, that was removed for the new modal
$(".modal-backdrop.in").addClass("fade");
```

(with the most recent Bootstrap versions, use `$(".modal-backdrop.show").addClass("fade")`),

The example with the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/bvalentino/f82z1wex/2/

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me
had old version
Special thank to [Antony GUEDJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2939245/antony-guedj) use his code

```
$('[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click', function() {
   if($('.modal').hasClass('show')){
     var modal = $('.modal.show')
     $(modal).modal('hide');
    }
});
```