# Can Javascript know if a user has selected the box that disables alerts (Prevent page from creating additional dialogues)

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I have a delete button and on `.mouseup` it creates an alert pop-up which lets the user confirm or cancel deleting that object.

**Here is my js for that:**

```
$(".deleteIcon")
.mouseover(function() { $(this).closest('li').css("opacity", "0.7"); 
}).mouseout(function() { $(this).closest('li').css({ "opacity": "1", "background-color": "#89b8d7" });
}).mousedown(function() { $(this).closest('li').css("background-color", "#b71124");
}).mouseup(function() {   
var txt;
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this file?");
    if (r == true) {
        $(this).closest('li').css("display", "none");
    } else {
        $(this).closest('li').css("display", "inline-block;");
    }

     });
```

**Problem:**
If the user selects (prevent this page from creating additional dialog boxes) option - it completely disables the delete function.

**Question:** 
How do I alter my current code to create a fallback for when the user disables the pop up boxes. ***For example:*** How would I write the code so that if the user disables the popup alert to confirm deleting the object then the object will just be deleted anyways without any additional warnings.

Thanks!

**-edit/clarification:**

I guess my real question is IS it possible in javascript to know if the user checked the box disabling the alert and in so create a function based off that information.

So i am not trying to prevent users from disabling the popup. But my popup enables the delete function for my object. So I simply wana add a bit of javascript that knows if the user disabled the alert and if so then the deleted button just deletes the object anyways without any popup safety net asking if the user is sure they wana delete it. I actually like that the user can disable the alert in-case they find it annoying.

Comment: Use a custom dialog, like bootstrap modal (for example).  That won't trigger the option to stop showing dialogs as it's not really a dialog (like an alert or confirm popup).

Comment: Yeah I was trying to avoid that. Is there a way to write my code like "IF prevent dialog box = checked then $(this).closest('li').css("display", "none"); ?

Comment: No - you're going to have to use a non-popup dialog.  There's no way around it.

Comment: If you could just handle blocked dialog boxes, that would defeat the whole purpose of blocking a dialog box (from a user's point of view).

Comment: This may help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182520/bootstrap-modal-hide-one-then-show-another  Scroll down to see my answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571015/how-to-detect-prevent-this-page-from-creating-additional-dialogs

Comment: @Chintan that does not help, Portal_Zii needs to use a custom modal like Archer recommend, its the default browsers behavior Portal_Zii is experiencing, its just not worth relying on a 'hack' to achieve what he wants.  A different approach like Bootstrap modal or similar is the best solution to rid of any uncertainty of his functions functionality, Portal_Zii if you need help let us know.

Comment: So i am not trying to prevent users from disabling the popup. But my popup enables the delete function for my object. So I simply wana add a bit of javascript that knows if the user disabled the alert and if so then the deleted button just deletes the object anyways without any popup safety net asking if the user is sure they wana delete it. I actually like that the user can disable the alert in-case they find it annoying.

Comment: I def dont have an issue coming up with an alternative pop up method - i just dont wana add a hunk of extra code for such a simple feature that only my boss will be using.

Comment: @Archer WIth my new clarification please tell me if thats possible.

Comment: I guess my real question is IS it possible in javascript to know if the user checked the box disabling the alert and in so create a function based off that information.

Comment: Yes but  also the answer to my question just with different search terms and explanation. I could not find that post before the person below posted their answer even after a long discussion period between multiple users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** converted to wiki because duplicate to [how to know whether modal boxes (alert, prompt, confirm…) have been disabled in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672490/how-to-know-whether-modal-boxes-alert-prompt-confirm-have-been-disabled-i)

What you could do is to measure the time the dialog was visible.

If it is was only visible less then some milliseconds then it most likely was not shown at all, or the user closed it immediately:

```
function customConfirm( msg ) {
  var startTime = new Date();
  var result = confirm(msg);
  var stopTime = new Date();

  if( stopTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime() < 100 ) {
     //do some fallback 
     //and call callback depending on how you implemented the fallback
  } else {
     callback(result);
  }
}

customConfirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?', function(r) {
  if (r == true) {
    $(this).closest('li').css("display", "none");
  } else {
    $(this).closest('li').css("display", "inline-block;");
  }
});
```

Comment: I have a button that launches the alert. Is there no way to do something else with that button if the alert fails to launch? How would I write the code like that? Im a total novice.

Comment: is this code saying: if the alert fails to display in that time then do something else. ?

Comment: so on .mouseup if the alert is not available/visible within x-amount-of-time then do this: "..." instead?

Comment: oh wow okay ill play with this and try to add to my current code. thanks!

Comment: @Portal_Zii no if the alter/confirm, was only visible for less then `x` millisecons, you could assumen that it was not visible at all. (the script execution is block while the dialog box is opened)

Comment: This seems to be the most recommended way of doing it. Some more examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672490/how-to-know-whether-modal-boxes-alert-prompt-confirm-have-been-disabled-i     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571015/how-to-detect-prevent-this-page-from-creating-additional-dialogs

Comment: add those links to your answer too please. Ill check back after I play around. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Marcelo yes thats exactly a duplicate, instead of mention it here you should also mark it as duplicate in the question.

Comment: Still cant figure out how to make it work with my current code. Keeps breaking it. @Marcelo